# Use of "setTimeout()" in my jQuery Expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I'm trying to add the JavaScript function `setTimeout()` to my jQuery expression.  Without the `setTimeout()` my function loads a partial view with updated information when I enter text into my textbox.  But, it loads the information with every keystroke.  My logic is that if I can put in a timer then when the user stops typing, a second later the data is updated.

As you can see I tried to put a `setTimeout()` in but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$(function() {
    $('#DocId').live('keyup', function() {
        setTimeout(var styleValue = $(this).val();
        $('#tableContent').load(
        '/CurReport/TableResults', 
        { style: $(this).val()}), 1000);

    }),
});
```

Thank you,

Aaron

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) and put in a delay timer that resets every keystroke like this:

```
$('#DocId').live('keyup', function() {
  clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
  var val = $(this).val();
  var wait = setTimeout(function() {
    $('#tableContent').load('/CurReport/TableResults', { style: val });
  }, 1000);
  $(this).data('timer', wait);
});
```

This sets a timeout of 1 second every keystroke on the element that it's typed it (can have any number of these going at once).  Each keystroke clears the previous timer and sets a new one, so only after 1 complete second of not typing will the function fire.

Note: don't remove the `var val = $(this).val();` portion, you need the variable because `this` is a different context when the function actually executes.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.  I've noticed that it has been you that has answered most of my JavaScript questions.